# ICS Form Widgets are different on Theme.NoTitleBar

Tags: android, eclipse, themes, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I have noticed that the default theme for ICS 4.0.3 in Eclipse is Theme.Holo which has the default ICS buttons, the blue ones.

However while fiddling about with the AndroidManifest.xml I decided to remove the title bar. That automatically switched the theme to Theme.NoTitleBar which has different form widgets.

Is there any way I can use the Holo theme with no title bar?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use the styles Theme_Holo_NoActionBar (or Theme_Holo_Light_NoActionBar).

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.style.html#Theme_Holo_NoActionBar
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.style.html#Theme_Holo_Light_NoActionBar

Comment: Thanks. That worked. What's the difference between action bar and title bar?

Comment: Pre Android 3.0 (Honeycomb) it was called Title bar since it was..well..a title bar. Then they introduced the Action bar, which is a title bar with action buttons (and it includes also the overflow menu button when needed).You can read more about this here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html